# Parsing comma separated string into multiple database entries (eg. Tags)

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I want to create a Symfony 2 Form for a Blog Post. One of the fields that I am wondering how might I implement is the tags field. `Post` has a many-to-many relationship with `Tag`. I want my Form to have 1 text box where users enter in a comma separated list of tags. Which will then be converted into multiple `Tag`'s.

How should I implement it? Do I:

- Have a `tagsInput` field (named differently from in the `Entity` where `$tags` should be an  `ArrayCollection`)
- On `POST`, I split the tags and create/get multiple tags. Then validate the tags (eg. MaxLength of 32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are already on the right way since I saw your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8463935/697930) about the form type. I will just comfort you with your choice.

A form type is probably the best way to go. With the form type, you will be able to display a single text field in your form. You will also be able to transform the data into a string for display to the user and to an `ArrayCollection` to set it in your model. For this, you use a `DataTransformer` exactly as you are doing in your other question.

With this technique, you don't need an extra field `tagsInput` in your model, you can have only a single field named `tags` that will an `ArrayCollection`. Having one field is possible because the you form type will transform that data from a string to an `ArrayCollection`.

For the validation, I think you could use the `Choice` validator. This validator directive seems to be able to validate that an array does not have less than a number of item and not more than another number. You can check the documentation for it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html). You would use it like this:

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/Author.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Post
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Choice(min = 1, max = 32)
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

If it does not work or not as intended, what you could do is to create a custom validator. This validator will then be put in your model for the `tags` field. This validator would validate the an array have a maximum number of element no greater than a fixed number (32 in your case).

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Thanks. I think you misunderstood the part on validation. Since the user is entering comma separated text for the tags. I wanted to validate each tag, is not more than 32 characters.

Comment: Yeah, I tought you wanted to be sure that there was no more than 32 tags. Then, You could instead create a custom constraint to validate it by put in back into a string and validate that there is at most 32 characters.