# Map a form's text field to an entity's ArrayCollection

Tags: php, forms, symfony, arraycollection

I am using tags on a form using [tagsinput](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) :

[image]

This plugin ends-up with a single text field containing tags separated by a comma (eg: tag1,tag2,...)

Those tags are currently managed on a non-mapped form field:

```
    $builder
       // ...
       ->add('tags', 'text', array(
               'mapped' => false,
               'required' => false,
       ))
    ;
```

And finally, they are stored on an ArrayCollection, as [this is a bad practice to store multiple values in a database field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699957/731138):

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[FiddleTag]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FiddleTag", mappedBy="fiddle", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $tags;
```

To map my form to my entity, I can do some code in my controller like this:

```
    $data->clearTags();
    foreach (explode(',', $form->get('tags')->getData()) as $tag)
    {
        $fiddleTag = new FiddleTag();
        $fiddleTag->setTag($tag);
        $data->addTag($fiddleTag);
    }
```

But this looks the wrong way at first sight.

I am wondering what is the best practice to map my entity to my form, and my form to my entity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is tricky since you aren't just embedding a collection of Tag forms that are say, all separate text fields. I suppose you could do that with some trickery, but what about using a data transformer instead?  You could convert a comma-separated list of tags to an ArrayCollection and pass that back to the form, and on the flip-side, take the collection and return the tags as a comma-separated string.

### Data transformer

<kbd>FiddleTagsTransformer.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\AppBundle\Transformer;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Fuz\AppBundle\Entity\FiddleTag;

class FiddleTagTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    public function transform($tagCollection)
    {
        $tags = array();

        foreach ($tagCollection as $fiddleTag)
        {
            $tags[] = $fiddleTag->getTag();
        }

        return implode(',', $tags);
    }

    public function reverseTransform($tags)
    {
        $tagCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach (explode(',', $tags) as $tag)
        {
            $fiddleTag = new FiddleTag();
            $fiddleTag->setTag($tag);
            $tagCollection->add($fiddleTag);
        }

        return $tagCollection;
    }

}
```

**Note**: you cannot specify ArrayCollection type to `public function transform($tagCollection)` because your implementation should match the interface.

### Form type

The second step is to replace your form field declaration so it will use the data transformer transparently, you'll not even need to do anything in your controller:

<kbd>FiddleType.php</kbd>

```
$builder
   // ...
   ->add(
        $builder
            ->create('tags', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
            ))
            ->addModelTransformer(new FiddleTagTransformer())
   )
;
```

### Validation

You can use [@Assert\Count](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html) to limit the number of allowed tags, and [@Assert\Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) if your FiddleTag entity has some validation constraints itself.

<kbd>Fiddle.php</kbd>

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[FiddleTag]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FiddleTag", mappedBy="fiddle", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Assert\Count(max = 5, maxMessage = "You can't set more than 5 tags.")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $tags;
```

### Further reading

See the Symfony2 doc about data transformers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

See these posts for some other ideas:

[Parsing comma separated string into multiple database entries (eg. Tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463138/parsing-comma-separated-string-into-multiple-database-entries-eg-tags)

[How does Symfony 2 find custom form types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463935/how-does-symfony-2-find-custom-form-types)

Comment: A [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) is exactly what I needed. I did not even know about it until now, thank you.

Comment: No problem - I threw that code together pretty quickly so if there's something quirky that doesn't work let me know.

Comment: I will edit your answer when the job'll be done if I find any, no problem. You gave me the right direction.